# replace image with lower resolutiion quality image on load with blazy plugin

Tags: javascript, image, lazy-loading, blazy

In this demo:

http://dinbror.dk/blazy/examples/?ref=blog

at paragraph:

**1.3: Lazy load image example with low res image placeholder**

the blazy plugin uses a lower quality pixely image to preload the image and then serve the high quality image right after.

I don't understand how that is done. Where is the pixely image coming from?
how to achieve the same effect with images? lower quality first and then load the right size?

Comment: The pixely image is coming from the `src` attribute, while the high resolution is stored in `data-src` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like that:

```
<img src='lowres.jpg' id='sampleImage' 
 onLoad='javascript:this.src = "highres.jpg"' />
```

After loading the low resolution version, the browser will execute the javascript and load the high resolution image, and replace the low resolution.

Comment: If you are going to make it inline (a bit of a bad practice) you can refer to the `img` element as `this`: `onLoad='this.src = "highres.jpg"'`

Comment: @yuriy636 it's just a limited sample to show how it can be done. OP should use a function to change the images. And thanks for `this.src`, I forgot about it...